# How to select all tenth in a field?

Tags: qgis, sql

I want to select all tenth in a field! :( I know this way; "Km" = 10 or "Km" = 20 ... and so, but I am pretty sure theres other way.

I am not SQL literate, but with your help in this forums I have managed to do some things, however the most basic are missing in different posts and I would like to find a place with basic (and medium) SQL expressions with practical examples to look for.
I don´t usually post, but this could be of interest for some people outside.

---

Para los que hablan español, esto es una pregunta muy básica y hasta tonta como dice el titulo, pero quisiera un sitio para encontrar expresiones SQL que son básicas, y que quizás para los que no somos letrados en esas "ciencias" podriamos usar de referencia, recuerdo la ayuda de ESRI tenía unos ejemplos de expresiones muy útiles y ultimamente con el Xtools resolvía.
Mi problema es sencillo:
Seleccionar todas las decimas de un campo de Numero de Kilometros. Se hacerlo seleccionando uno por uno ("Km" = 10 or "Km" = 20, y asi) pero debe haber una forma más sencilla.... que pena preguntar algo tan básico pero tanta búsqueda en foros y demás, todos piensan que ya uno maneja estas cosas básicas.
saludos!

Comment: Additional solutions appear at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9157 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54887.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question, but it looks like it can be achieved with

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE chosencolumn % 10 = 0`

I'm not sure about the syntax, but if you want to pick all the whole ten's from an integer field this should work.